# Node.js + Typescript + Webpack = Module not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm new with Webpack, Node.js and Typescript and I'm having trouble configuring my dev enviroment.

When running `webpack` to compile my `src/server.ts` to generate the `/server/bundle.js` I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/server.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hapi' in '/Volumes/Dados/giovane/dev/studio-hikari/nodang/nodang-api/src'
 @ ./src/server.ts 3:11-26
```

The architecture of the project is:

[image]

The `src/server.ts`:

```
import * as Hapi from 'hapi';

const server = new Hapi.Server();
```

The `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/server.ts',
  output: {
    filename: './server/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve('src'),
      path.resolve('node_modules')
    ]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.ts$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

The `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "nodang-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "webpack --progress --watch",
    "serve": "node-dev server/bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/hapi": "^16.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.8",
    "tsd": "^0.6.5",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

### OBS: It's webpack 2

### UPDATE

After installing `hapi` and adding `.js` to webpack's resolve extentions and `node` as webpack's target I'm getting this erros with hapi modules:

```
ERROR in ./~/hapi/lib/server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'catbox' in '/Volumes/Dados/giovane/dev/studio-hikari/nodang/nodang-api/node_modules/hapi/lib'
 @ ./~/hapi/lib/server.js 5:15-32
 @ ./~/hapi/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

ERROR in ./~/hapi/lib/server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'catbox-memory' in '/Volumes/Dados/giovane/dev/studio-hikari/nodang/nodang-api/node_modules/hapi/lib'
 @ ./~/hapi/lib/server.js 6:21-45
 @ ./~/hapi/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts
```

Comment: could you show your package.json file?

Comment: @AnyName just added

Comment: `test: /\.ts$/,` may be you would escape the `.`

Comment: @Jai did it, same thing

Comment: import * as Hapi from '@types/hapi';

Comment: @Giovane i don't see hapi in the dependencies. seems you forgot to install this dependency and you just installed the types only.

Comment: @Jai Hapi is in the dependencies. ` "@types/hapi": "^16.0.0" `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You did not install `hapi`. `@types/hapi` are just the type definitions that TypeScript uses for the library, but not the actual library itself. So you need to add `hapi` as well:

```
npm install --save hapi
```

Once you've installed it, the module can be found, although you'll get a new error that `./server` could not be resolved in `hapi/lib/index.js` and that's because you configure `resolve.extensions` to only include `.ts`, but the library makes use of Node automatically resolving `.js` when leaving off the extension. So you also need to include `.js` in the extensions:

```
extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
```

After also resolving this issue, you'll be faced with another one, namely that Node built-in modules like  `fs` can't be resolved. By default webpack builds for the web, so the Node built-in modules are not available. But you can change that by setting the [target](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/) option in your webpack config to `node`:

```
target: 'node'
```

## Edit

You're having trouble with other `node_modules` because you only use the top level `node_modules`, instead you want to always fall back to the regular module resolution of `node_modules`, so the [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) should look like this:

```
modules: [
  path.resolve('src'),
  'node_modules'
]
```

Comment: Great answer! I would like to ask a question. Is there any practical reason for using webpack targeting node.js? Thanks

Comment: I guess the main reason is to have a production build that only includes what is necessary (which can be optimised) and all you need to run the app, is the bundle (and Node of course), without having to install any dependencies.

Comment: Great, now it's compiling hapi. But I got new errors from hapi modules.

Comment: I edited the answer to resolve that issue. I didn't have that issue because I'm using [Yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn) and it installs those dependencies to the top level as opposed to what npm does.

Comment: Man, you're my hero! Everything is working fine! I just had to remove the `"typeRoots": ["node_modules"]` I put on the `tsconfig.json`.